# Local complete intersection scheme, conormal sheaves and differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $Z \subset X$ be a local complete intersection subscheme in $X$. Denote by $I_Z$ the ideal sheaf of $Z$ in $X$ and $\Omega^1_X$ the sheaf of Kähler differentials. Then, is it true that the map from $I_Z/I_Z^2 \to \Omega^1_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_Z$ induced by the differential map, injective? If not, without assuming $Z$ to be smooth is there any condition, under which this map can be injective, for example if $Z$ is a divisor?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What methods have you attempted already? It appears as if you simply copied a problem to this site. That is not encouraged; rather, we look for questions that include more context about where the problem was encountered, why it is interesting, and what the asker has attempted.

Comment: @Mummert: There is a canonical way of trying the problem using the differential map. Also, anybody familiar with basic algebraic geometry will notice at once the interesting part of the problem, namely we have injectivity in the case of smooth varieties, but since $I_Z/I_Z^2$ is locally free, one is tempted to think this might hold true as well.

Comment: Consider the case $X$ is the affine line over a positive characteristic field and $Z$ is a supported in a single closed point.

Comment: @cantlog: I am sorry, I am for now interested on $\mathbb{C}$. I am editing the question.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Although you no doubt mean well, and your comment above is appropriate for many questions on this site, this particular question does not appear to be "simply copied"

Comment: @user54369: OK. If $Z$ is reduced, then this is true because the kernel will be supported in a positive codimension closed subset of $Z$, this can't happen as a submodule of a locally free module. Without this hypothesis, the injectivity doesn't hold: consider $Z$ a fat point in the affine line.